# What's wrong with this rsync command?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I want to recursively copy all mp3 files from source to destination using rsync (on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I am using the command below. It is copying all of the folders and subfolders (creating empty folders on the destination), but none of the mp3 files. What have I done wrong?

```
sudo rsync -zarv --include "*/" --exclude="*" --include="*.mp3" /media/oldfolder/ /media/newfolder
```

Comment: put the includes before the excludes.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it! I didn't realise that precedence applied to the order of the arguments

Comment: And use `--prune-empty-dirs` too